# jQuery starts with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[class^=\"hide\"]").hide();
    });
</script>

<div class="hide1">Hide</div>
<div class="show1">Show</div>
<div class="hide2">Hide</div>
<div class="show2">Show</div>
<div class="hide3">Hide</div>
<div class="show3">Show</div>
<div class="hide4">Hide</div>
<div class="show4">Show</div>
```

But on page load, the `hide` divs are still visible... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [It works in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2GzpA) You did include the jQuery library, right?

Comment: Yeah. I'm using MVC3, and I included jquery-1.5.1.min.js

Comment: Check your developer console and see if any JS errors are being encountered elsewhere.

Comment: Why have you got so many classes? Why not just use `hide` and `show`?

Comment: @Tomgrohl well my code is actually much more complicated. I need to be able to hide and show each div individually.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: you could get rid of the escaped quotes in selectors. Try `$("[class^=hide]").hide();` and tell us if it works

Comment: @Grooveek jQuery needs the quotes so it will be valid

Comment: Sorry to waste your time... it was just a stupid mistake on my part. (See my answer)

Comment: See my answer for a full explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow... I feel *so* stupid. I spent so much time banging my head against a wall, and only discover the solution after I post here...

So turns out I was doing everything correctly, but the `div`s were in a View (I'm using MVC3) that was being loaded after `$(document).ready` was being called. Moving the code into the View solved the problem.

Comment: Nah, it's alright. At least you figured it out in the end, and it's something we probably couldn't have thought of either!

Comment: JavaScript, strictly, should not be included directly into Views as Views represent markup and should be as thin/stupid as possible. Should this code be included in an a `$.Get()`/`$.Post()`/`$(selector).Load()` success handler in a script?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have separate classes for those? Why not have a single hide class and set those attributes above (e.g. `"hide1"`) as ids, then your selector can simply be on that class e.g. `$('div.hide')`?

See http://jsfiddle.net/2GzpA/1/ for an example.

EDIT:
For your question, you comment:

> @Tomgrohl well my code is actually much more complicated. I need to be able to hide and show each div individually.

Why not add a separate class to use for this case? Then your selector becomes `$('div.specificCaseHideClass')`. You can have as many classes as you like and this is a fine example of when to add one.

Comment: Well my code is actually much more complicated. I need to be able to hide and show each div individually.

Answer (score 0):

try this its simple

```
$("div:even").hide();
```

Comment: No, it's not so simple. This is way too big an assumption about the structure of the markup.

Comment: Yes. There are other divs in my code in between the ones in question.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins i like ur Question due... i learned many thing from ur question thanks to post..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that jquery is included?  This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6ycbT/

Also, check your js console to see if any errors are getting thrown that might prevent this code from executing

Answer (score 0):

switch out the outer quotes by single quotes and it works:

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geertvdc/hv4Ls/

code:

```
$('[class^="hide"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[class*=hide]").hide();
});
```